# PACKAGE.TABLENAME%ROWTYPE in JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

We have a stored proc where it returns a record which is of type PACKAGE.TABLENAME%ROWTYPE. we are finding it difficult to map in JDBC? Does anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: This is Oracle you're working with?

Comment: It's a shot in the dark, considering the vague way the question is worded, but here's a Sun Java forum link to check out on the matter of making %ROWTYPE work with JDBC: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5363452

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find a better solution. So changed the  stored proc to return a REF cursor.